# open_basedir restriction in effect error in php code

Tags: php, filepath, document-root, open-basedir

Im beginner in php language. in my web project i created a filepath.config.ini file which stores all file path in the website directories. for eg.
CLASS1 = bin/myclass1.php
CLASS2 = bin/myclass2.php

and im accessing those path by using:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.GetfilePath('CLASS1');
```

in localhost server its working good and giving me path like this

```
D:/myproject/bin/myclass1.php
```

when i upload those file on test server im getting this open_basedir restriction error.

```
Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/projectfolder/bin/myclass1.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp)
```

i know we can disable this restriction...but i dont know how to do that :P.
but is it good to use this server DOCUMENT_ROOT ???
or is their any alternate way to use the file path? what you people do to access those file path.
and what happen if i disable the open_basedir restriction? is it secure to do that?
please help me what to do?

Comment: The error points to a local path (?): **File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/projectfolder/bin/myclass1.php) is not within the allowed path(s)**

Answer (score 1):

Edit your php.ini file ([PHP: Configuration Changes](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)) and either disable [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) or add /usr/local/apache/htdocs to it.